# Display role of administrator next to the username in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to display an extra text next to the Username if the person has the `administrator` role?

I just want to display the extra text for this role only, what hook could I use for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the filter `the_author`, like so:

```
add_filter( 'the_author', 'author_admin_so_14367149' );

function author_admin_so_14367149( $display_name ) 
{
    // Block the filter in the dashboard (admin area)
    if( is_admin() )
        return $display_name;

    global $authordata;

    // User has administrator role, add string to display name
    if( in_array( 'administrator', $authordata->roles ) )
        $display_name = $display_name . ' (admin)';

    return $display_name;
}
```

For the comments section, there's another filter and the checks are different:

```
add_filter( 'get_comment_author', 'comment_author_admin_so_14367149' );

function comment_author_admin_so_14367149( $author ) 
{
    // Block the filter in the dashboard (admin area)
    if( is_admin() )
        return $author;

    $user = get_user_by( 'login', $author );

    // User has administrator role, add string to display name
    if( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) )
        $author = $author . ' (admin)';

    return $author;
}
```

Comment: thanks! it worked!...how about if there is more than 1 admin?

Comment: Check [the other properties](http://wpsmith.net/2012/wp/an-introduction-to-wp_user-class/) of the User Object.

Comment: So, I got it working but I have another question. The admin next to my username only shows when I'm the author of a post otherwise there is no admin next to it when I comment on someone else' post...why is that?

Comment: Thanks! it's almost perfect :) but with the new add_filter everyone else is displaying admin right next to their username

Comment: I think/hope it is alright now, and, if so, you owe me a beer :o[)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, I really appreciate you - where should I send the beer? :P ...Ok, here's what I did with the first one when there's more than 1 admin: I changed author_admin_so_14367149 to author_is_admin and that worked. on the second one I didn't change anything thought it worked, but the other admin who comments on other people's post shows warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given